# Oracle Date column storing time, but not displaying it

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, datetime, user-interface

I have a oracle database backend linked to a C# Visual Studio Application.

I have a INVOICE table that stores a few Dates.

In the UI, i databind a DateTimePicker to these fields.  The user selects both DATE and TIME.  These values are stored to the database and are retriveable later, but i do not see the time in the Oracle interface.

C# DataSet Visualizer:
[image]

Oracle data view
[image]

Notice that both images are looking at the same table, first from Visual studio, and next from Oracle.  The TIME is stored between sessions somewhere, as it can be retrieved and populates the user interface control which this column is bound to :

[image]

The problem is i want to run SQL in ORACLE and export the data to EXCEL, but since the TIME isn't visible in the ORACLE table, I cannot it for the EXCEL Report.

Is this a setting? or some weird caching issue or what?

Comment: are you writing the SQL query?  if so, then you can use TO_CHAR to convert the date/time to many formats of your choosing.

Comment: @Randy even so, shouldn't i be able to see the TIME in the column in oracle? or is it hiding it behind the scenes?  I will give this a shot, as i am writing the SQL

Comment: there is a default format for dates that is set for the instance - typically you can't count on this for an app, so best practice will be to select it in the format you want

Comment: @Randy Wow, that is awesome, i just ran it against my data like this 
//select to_char(my_date,'dd/mm/yyyy, HH24:MI:SS') "CustomColName" from invoice;\\ and it worked perfectly.  You should make it an answer an ill accept it sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok here is a gratuitous answer :)

please use the `TO_CHAR` function to return the date in your desired format.